# Cómo extender una plantilla blade desde un componente Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel

hace mucho que estoy investigando y buscando la solución a esta pregunta.

Tengo mi pagina de inicio donde quiero que todo sea un componente Livewire (nav y body).

Este es mi Controlador Livewire `inicio.php`

```
class Inicio extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.inicio')->extends('app')->section('content');
    }
}
```

Esta es mi página raíz `app.blade.php` hubicada en `Resources/views`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la vista del controlador livewire: `inicio.blade.php` hubicada en `Resources/views/livewire`

Tengo cargado el `@livewireStyles` y `@livewireScripts` de manera correcta asi que no creo tener problemas con las dependencias. sencillamente me carga solo la vista de inicio pero no extiende de la plantilla `app.blade.php`. He intentado de varias maneras pero el resultado es el mismo, es como si los métodos `extends()` y `section()` no funcionaran.

P/D: estoy utilizando `Laravel v8.83.25 (PHP v8.1.6)`

Answer (score 0):

LiveWire tiene una directiva Blade para insertar las vistas, trata con:

```
<div> @livewire('inicio') </div>
```